# How can I write an inspec kitchen test that will verify that a web service on the node is reachable

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

I have a chef recipe that installs a web service. I want to write an inspec test that verifies this. So my thought was to write the following test:

```
# Verify that the service is running.
describe http('http://localhost/myservice/healthcheck') do
  its('status') { should eq 200 }
end
```

I ran 'kitchen verify mynode' and get a "connection refused" error for this test. I suspect that means that the test is connecting to my workstation rather than the localhost of the node being tested. So how does one write a test to verify that a web service is running?

Comment: No, InSpec runs inside the instance.

Comment: The http resource then seems pretty useless to me. I finally found the github issue talking about this. Hopefully they'll get around to fixing it.

Comment: This is not correct, InSpec does not run on the instance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `kitchen-inspec` runs the test code on the machine running Test Kitchen, as you noted. You can either use something like `command('curl -v http://localhost/whatever')` and parse the output or switch back to `busser-serverspec`.